# ArrayList Database MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, arraylist

Have very limited experience with databases and trying to figure out the best method for creating a growing database of users and keeping track of their growing information when added.

For instance, I have 3 users - **Apple, Banana, Cherry**. And they all have a list of information associated with them.

```
  Apple: [1/1/17, green, 3], [2/4/17, red, 5], [4/19/17, blue, 2]
  Banana: [2/18/17, yellow, 6], [5/14/17, yellow, 5] 
  Cherry: [5/21/17, green, 12], [8/2/17, red, 5], [9/29/17, blue, 42], 
  [1/1/17, green, 3]
```

Before even getting into working with a growing list, how does this get applied to a database?

Do I create a main database, something like **FruitDatabase**, and then inside those databases have Apple, Banana, and Cherry as their own tables?

Or does each **user** get their own database and then their associated information get applied to their own table (that doesn't seem efficient)?

What if I later want to add up all of Apple's number (3+5+2), what's the best method of doing that? It doesn't seem like I can put an **ArrayList** into a database, do I just convert it into a string and separate the number with a comma? And if I want to add a new user, DragonFruit, is it more efficient to add it as a column or row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create tables like the following to represent your data.

```
create table fruit_type (
  fruit_type_id int,
  name varchar(20),
  color varchar(10),
  primary key(fruit_type_id)
);

create table fruits (
 fruit_id int,
 date_added date,
 count int,
 foreign key (fruit_id) references fruit_type(fruit_type_id)
)
```

Before inserting data into `fruits` table, you need to have a row for each fruit type in `fruit_type` table.

Answer (score 0):

The way this works is that you should have 1 database/schema for your entire application say Fruit_Management. Within that you should have one table called Fruits.
This Fruits table will have 5 columns namely id, type, date, colour and qty.
which will map to 1, Apple, 1/1/17, green, 3. Now if you want to get the total number of apples you write aggregation queries like select count(*) from Fruits where Fruits.type='Apple'.

This way your schema remains flexible and normalized.